# ClassCastException $Proxy cannot be cast to using aop

Tags: java, spring, aop

I was using spring to create objects through beans. Now I tried to use aop to create the same object and I get $Proxy cannot be cast to SaleRoom exception.

the previous xml was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd"
xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config- 1.0.xsd"
xmlns:jm s="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-2.5.xsd"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd"
xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.5.xsd"
xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd/spring-spring-aop-2.5.xsd-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd/spring-spring-context-2.5.xsd-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-1.0.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-1.0.xsd/spring-spring-webflow-config-1.0.xsd-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-2.5.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-2.5.xsd/spring-spring-jms-2.5.xsd-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd/spring-spring-jee-2.5.xsd-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.5.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.5.xsd/spring-spring-lang-2.5.xsd-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd/spring-spring-osgi.xsd-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd/spring-spring-tx-2.5.xsd-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd/spring-spring-util-2.5.xsd-2.5.xsd
">
<bean id="sale01" class="application.common.entities.BidRoom">
<property name="itemId" value="0001"/>
<property name="lifeTime" value="15"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

And I used the following code to create the sales:

```
    ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(SalesManager.getSalesSourceFile());
    SaleRoom saleRoom;
    List<String> salesNames = new LinkedList<String>();
    List<SaleRoom> allSales = new LinkedList<SaleRoom>();

    // Get all sales id's for beans
    NodeList salesNodeList = salesDoc.getElementsByTagName("bean");

    for (int i = 0; i < salesNodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node nNode = salesNodeList.item(i);
        salesNames.add(((Element) nNode).getAttribute("id").toString());
    }

    for (String saleName : salesNames) {
        if(saleName.contains("sale")) {
            saleRoom = (SaleRoom) context.getBean(saleName);
            allSales.add(saleRoom);
        }
    }

    return allSales;
```

This is the new xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
        <aop:include name="logSettersCalls"/>
    </aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
    <bean id="logSettersCalls" class="application.logging.aop.LogSettersCalls"/>

    <bean id="sale01" class="application.common.entities.BidRoom">
        <constructor-arg index="0" type="int" value="0001"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" type="int" value="15"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The Aspect logging class:

```
@Aspect
public class LogSettersCalls {
   @Pointcut("execution(void set*(*))")
    public void setMethod() {}

    @Before("setMethod()")
    public void logSetterCall(JoinPoint theJoinPoint) {
        String methodName = theJoinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        Object newValue = theJoinPoint.getArgs()[0];
        Object theObject = theJoinPoint.getTarget();
        System.out.println("The method " + methodName + " is called on object " 
                + theObject + " with the value " + newValue);
    }
}
```

I'm using the same code for creating the beans via aop. and I get 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy11 cannot be cast to application.common.entities.SaleRoom

The line that throws the exception: 
saleRoom = (SaleRoom) context.getBean(saleName);

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Does your SaleRoom class implement some interface? If yes, then you should use interface and not class in you code:

```
ISaleRoom saleRoom = (ISaleRoom) context.getBean(saleName);
```

Because if your bean implements some interface then Spring by default will create proxy based on this interface.

Here is [a good article about proxy creation in Spring.](http://blog.springsource.org/2007/07/19/debunking-myths-proxies-impact-performance/)

Also you can change proxying mechanism for Spring AOP if you want to create proxy for target class. This is described [here in reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch08s06.html).

Comment: My SaleRoom extends Thread and does not implement any interface.

Comment: I think that the reason of problem is that Thread implements Runnable. Try to create your own business interface (for example ISaleRoom) where define business methods that you need to access. Then in code cast to interface (ISaleRoom) context.getBean(saleName) as I mentioned in answer.

Comment: Or you can try to change proxying mechanism (look at the link that I posted).

Comment: Yes! you are right. I changed it to 
Runaable r = (Runaable) context.getBean(saleName);
and there was no error. unfortunately, this doesn't help me because I can't case from runnable to SaleRoom.
I also can't really understand how can I change the proxying mechanism. Are you able to give some directions about it? Thanks!

Comment: Also the option of creating ISaleRoom Interface is the last resort cause I'd have to change a lot of code for implementing that.

Comment: For changing proxying mechanizm to proxy target clas define define aspectj-autoproxy like this: <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>

Comment: Thanks a lot dimas! Oddly that worked. I say oddly because I tried it numerous times.. but this time I downgraded my project to previous version. Something must have been wrong there. The object is now created but the logging in being missed, meaning it doesn't enter the LogSettersCalls method any ideas?

Comment: Likely your pointcut definition is wrong. But better ask this in separate question where described in more details what you suppose to do with AOP, how it is actually working now and post more code related to setters that  you want to log. Because this question is too overloaded.