# class cast exception while initializing bean using ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, maven, aop, applicationcontext

I need your help in solving an issue concerning spring bean initialization. below is the details of the issue:

dao interface

```
  package com.dao;

  import com.entity.Employee;

  public interface IEmployeeDao {

       Employee create(final Employee aEmployee);
       Employee fetchEmployeeById(final Integer aEmployeeId);
  }
```

The dao impl class

```
  package com.dao.impl;

  import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

  import com.dao.IEmployeeDao;
  import com.entity.Employee;

  public class EmployeeDao implements IEmployeeDao {

      private EntityManager em;

      @Override
      public Employee create(Employee aEmployee) {
           return this.em.merge(aEmployee);
      }

      @Override
      public Employee fetchEmployeeById(Integer aEmployeeId) {
         return this.em.find(Employee.class, aEmployeeId);
      }
  }
```

the main class :

```
  package com.client;

  import java.sql.SQLException;

  import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
  import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
  import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
  import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

  import com.dao.impl.EmployeeDao;

  public class Client {
       private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Client.class);

       public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, 
          SQLException {
       ApplicationContext applicationContext = new 
       ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"applicationcontext.xml"});
       LOGGER.info("client invoked");
       EmployeeDao employeeDao =  
         (EmployeeDao)applicationContext.getBean("employeeDao");    
       //....some code below
     }
   }
```

the last line in the code where I am trying to get employeeDao bean is throwing the below exception :

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
  com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17 cannot be cast to 
  com.dao.impl.EmployeeDao
  at com.client.Client.main(Client.java:26)
```

as suggested in some of the answers I browsed, I changed the above line to cast to an interface instead of its implementation class

```
    IEmployeeDao employeeDao =  
         (IEmployeeDao)applicationContext.getBean("employeeDao");
```

the bean is getting injected without any exception, but now the actual implementation methods are not being invoked i.e now when I call the create method of EmployeedDao like below

```
  employeeDao.create(new Employee());
```

the create methods implementation is not getting called i.e the below method:

```
  @Override
  public Employee create(Employee aEmployee) {
       System.out.println("com.dao.impl.EmployeeDao.create(Employee) callled")
       return this.em.merge(aEmployee);
  }
```

I confirmed it by placing a sysout message.

Please suggest me what I am doing wrong or what can be done to get away with this issue. I have also posted the bean configuration files and maven depedencies below.

applicationcontext.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd ">
    <import resource="aspects.xml"/>
    <bean id="employeeDao" class="com.dao.impl.EmployeeDao" />

    </beans>
```

aspects.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd ">

         <bean id="logAspect" 
               class="com.logging.LoggingAspect" />

         <aop:config>

            <aop:aspect id="aspectLoggging" ref="logAspect">
            <aop:pointcut id="pointCutAround"
                 expression="execution(* 
         com.dao.IEmployeeDao.*(..))" />

         aop:around method="logAround" pointcut-ref="pointCutAround" />

     </aop:aspect>
     </aop:config>
     </beans>
```

maven dependencies :

```
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.3</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.3</version>
     </dependency>      
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <version>10.13.1.1</version>
     </dependency>  
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
       <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

EDIT :

LoggingAspect class:

```
  package com.logging;

  import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
  import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
  import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;

  public class LoggingAspect {
       private static final Logger LOGGER = 
          LogManager.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);
       public void logAround(JoinPoint aJoinPoint) {
               LOGGER.info("aspects logging enabled");
       }
 }
```

Comment: "but now the actual implementation methods are not being invoked." Can you be more clear ?

Comment: @davidxxx I just now edited that part,I hope its clear now ?

Comment: Your error is caused by using AOP on that bean. Try to remove aop xml from spring config and run initial version of code. Also, you are using very old spring-context and spring-aop version. I suggest using latest release version ```<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>```

Comment: @IvanPronin yes I know the problem is associated with aop usage, and I had tried without it and it works like you said, but I have to use aop so could you please suggest what the actual problem could be and how to deal with it ?

Comment: @IvanPronin also regarding the version would it really matter ? I mean I know I should be using the latest version but do you think the problem is caused because of the older version ?

Comment: Regarding aop - please, look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461985/classcastexception-proxy-cannot-be-cast-to-using-aop) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141237/java-lang-classcastexception-com-sun-proxy-proxy0-cannot-be-cast-to-org-andrea) questions. Regarding spring versions - as any software, spring has bugs inside it. So, using newer versions gives more stable and free of bugs framework.

Comment: @IvanPronin I had already referred to these questions before posting my query, also I have changed the bean initialization to Interface now like posted above, but in that case I am facing another issue, and thats something I am looking an answer for

Comment: Your logging aspect is probably not invoking the instrumented code. Post the aspect code.

Comment: @Strelok  I have added the aspect code, do you see any problem with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a problem with your Aspect. It is not actually invoking the instrumented code. Try this:

```
public void logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint aJoinPoint) { // <<-- don't forget to change the type to ProceedingJoinPoint
  LOGGER.info("aspects logging enabled");
  aJoinPoint.proceed(); // this will continue to the instrumented code
}
```

Comment: thanks a ton.it worked, it only took me some time to mark your answer as the accepted one as I was doing some research as to why proceedingJoinPoint.proceed() is needed, and it was good to learn that its only needed for around advice and not for the rest of advice types. Its also mentioned in sring-aop documentation but probably i missed to read that part.